# Как получить value обоих td, находящихся внутри tr и (!) слить обе td в одну переменную в формате td1 : td2 ;

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер, cheerio

**Имеется** такой код:

```
<table class="tableUnder">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="local">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/24"> Материал </td>
      <td> Оцинкованная сталь </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="few">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/25"> Количество комплектующих </td>
      <td> 12/6/3 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="local">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/26"> Установка в подарок к покупке </td>
      <td>  </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="few">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/27"> Дополнительный ключ </td>
      <td>  </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Нужно:** забрать все характеристики из td, и сформировать их в переменную примерно таким образом:

Материал : Оцинкованная сталь ; Количество комплектующих : 12/6/3 ; Установка в подарок к покупке : есть ; Дополнительный ключ : есть ;
(там, где второе значение td - пустое - нужно, чтобы прописывалось "есть" вместо пустоты)

Я пытался сделать таким образом:

```
unique.map(async (el, i) => {
            const content = await getHtml(el.link)

            content('table.tableUnder').each((index, element) => {

                let allTr = content(element).find('tr') 
                // const allTd = content(element).find('td') // здесь строка из td целиком
                let param = content(element).find('td')
                let propString = ""
                for (index = 0; index < param.length; index++){
                    const row = content(param[index]).find('td')
                    const name = row[0]
                    const value = row[1]
                    propString += (` ${name.children[0].data.trim()} : ${value.children[0].data.trim()} ; `)
                    el.propString = propString
                    console.log(el)
                


        
                
            })
})
```

Я могу получить строку, где друг за другом будут все td (`const allTd = content(element).find('td')`), однако мне нужно получить их в определенном виде (выше я показывал в каком виде). И я также думаю, что, чтобы получить нужные мне значения я мог бы использовать .children по индексу [0] или [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krdyH.png) .

Но я получаю ошибку : (node:4196) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined
[image: характеристика лежит в children[0].data]

Как я могу получить значения td в нужном формате  ? (использую node js + cheerio.)

> Материал : Оцинкованная сталь ; Количество комплектующих : 12/6/3 ; Установка в подарок к покупке : есть ; Дополнительный ключ : есть ;
> (там, где второе значение td - пустое - нужно, чтобы прописывалось "есть" вместо пустоты)

Comment: Немного переформулирую вопрос. Есть множество tr. В одной tr содержится две td. В переменную 'a' мне нужно получить значение первой td, в переменную 'b' мне нужно получить значение второй td. (в случае, если второй td - пуст - value 'b' = "есть")

Answer (score 0):

Вам, случайно, не подойдёт простой объект, то есть пары ключ/значение? Вот такой:

```js
{
  "Материал": "Оцинкованная сталь",
  "Количество комплектующих": "12/6/3",
  "Установка в подарок к покупке": "есть",
  "Дополнительный ключ": "есть"
}
```

Если да, можно превратить вашу таблицу в него, например, вот так:

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table.tableUnder');

const data = Object.fromEntries(
  [...table.rows].map(row => [...row.cells].map(
    cell => cell.innerText.trim() || 'есть'
  ))
);

console.log(data);
```

```html
<table class="tableUnder">
  <tbody>

    <tr class="local">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/24"> Материал </td>
      <td> Оцинкованная сталь </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="few">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/25"> Количество комплектующих </td>
      <td> 12/6/3 </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="local">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/26"> Установка в подарок к покупке </td>
      <td>  </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="few">
      <td> <a href ="/somepath/27"> Дополнительный ключ </td>
      <td>  </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. В node js нет доступа к элементу document, поэтому я использовал  ` const table = content(element).find('table.tableUnder') ` , чтобы положить содержимое таблицы в переменную (в content лежит весь html страницы.) Однако, ошибка всё же есть: ` table.rows is not iterable `

Comment: Погодите, если вы выполняете код не в браузере, это стоит подробнее описать в вопросе. Вы парсите HTML в Node.js чем-то вроде JSDom или Cheerio? Откуда берётся функция `content`? Какой тип данных возвращает `content(element).find('table.tableUnder')`?

Comment: Да, Парсинг с помощью **cheerio**, вы правы. В переменной **content** лежит весь html страницы (по аналогии с document). Content - это переменная, которую я создал, и положил в неё html страницы ( html забрал с помощью метода getHtml. getHtml получил вот так: const getHtml =  async (url) => {
        const {data} = await axios.get(url); return cheerio.load(data)
    }). Тип данных переменной в которую кладём content(element).find('table.tableUnder') = **object**

Comment: К сожалению, я не знаю ни cheerio, ни jQuery. Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что `.find('table.tableUnder')` возвращает коллекцию элементов или специальный объект-обёртку, а не обычный элемент DOM, поэтому `table.rows` не работает. Попробуйте получить обычный элемент. Может, нужно обратиться к результату find по нулевому индексу и тогда `table.rows` заработает.